# Working with Django Forms

Tags: django, forms

Cant any one give me a little bit insights on Django's forms, how to work with it and what are bound and unbound forms?

Comment: What part of the Django Tutorial have you read?   This seems clear: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/.  What part confused you?  Can you provide specific quotes or links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bound form is a form with data on its field, hence it can do validation. An unbound form is a form with no data on it (new initialized forms).

You should look and the official Django's [guide on working with forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and its [API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/).